# Tell clangd to look in usr/local/include

Tags: c++, ide, clangd

I use clangd in vscode with cmake normally and it works great, but I'm now working on a proect where the build is done with `poetry` and clangd doesn't know about any of the dependencies. I'm getting all sorts of editor cruft relating to undefined headers.

A simple fix would be to make clangd look into `/usr/local/include` to resolve a lot of issues. Is there a simple config file I can add to the root of my project to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this quite quickly, but for anyone looking in the future I solved this by placing a `compile_flags.txt` in the directory with the cpp source code as documented at the end of the [clangd docs](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html#alternatives) for use in simple situations.

It contains ..

```
-xc++
-I
/usr/local/include
```